# How come when I read in this file and scan in an int, the number that is outputted is REALLY large?

Tags: c, stack, scanf, infix-notation

I have to do this for a homework assignment, but I'm wondering why this is happening to me:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char* name;
printf("Please enter the name of the file: \n");
scanf("%s", &name);
FILE * input;
input = fopen("input1.txt", "w");
if(input == NULL)
{
    printf("This file does not exist");
}
else
{
char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
int infixOrPostfix;
int i = 0, j;
}


while(fscanf(input, "%s", line[i]) != '0')
{
    printf("%d", infixOrPostfix);
    if(infixOrPostfix == 1)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%s", &line);
        evaluateInfix(line);
    }
    else if(infixOrPostfix == 2)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%s", line);
        printf("%s", line);
        evaluatePostfix(line);
    }
    i++;
}
fclose(input);
free(line);
}
```

And when I run this part with the print statement, it prints out a VERY large number, when the number I was hoping it would print would be 2. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for any answers, and I can tell you right now, I am not very fond of my lack of skill with c.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char * name;
```

Replace with

```
 char name[255];
```

And read somethig about static and dynamic memory allocation.

---

```
 char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

This is wrong, I'll let you figure out why.

Comment: Is it because I didn't initialize how many elements there will be?

Comment: Hint, what is `sizeof(char)` and how much memory are you expecting to allocate.

Comment: Oh it's only 1 byte.